# make only the clicked item on a list active in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is probably really easy, I want to show the info of a list item when a user clicks on the item, however, the code I have will open the info of all list items when clicked.

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-lichterman-j1vpd?file=/src/App.js:0-599

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const list = [1, 2, 3];
export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((item, idx) => {
        return (
          <>
            <li
              onClick={() => {
                setActive(!active);
              }}
            >
              {item}
              <div className={active ? "active" : "info"}>
              {" "}
              Info {idx + 1}
            </div>
            </li>
            
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: because you set the same active hook for all of the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to toggle active only which is used by all items. Instead use index position to toggle.

I have explained the rest within the code using comments.

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const list = [1, 2, 3];
export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      {/* You forgot to add ul here */}
      <ul>
        {list.map((item, idx) => {
          return (
            // Added key to each child to avoid error. Use <React.Fragment/> instead of <>
            <React.Fragment key={idx}>
              <li
                onClick={() => {
                  // Condition for toggling the lists.
                  // If current list is selected
                  if (active === idx) {
                    // change active to blank
                    setActive();
                  } else {
                    // change active to current index
                    setActive(idx);
                  }
                }}
              >
                {item}
              </li>
              <div className={active === idx ? "info active" : "info"}>
                {" "}
                Info {idx + 1}
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edited this css to avoid applying to another tag
style.css

```
.info.active {
  display: flex;
}
```

You can try the above code on sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-qno-65730790-tmeyf

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good use case for [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). It's a really useful tool to keep track of the states of multiple components. In your case you would need to track whether a given LI is active (showing information) or not. Here is how to do that with `useReducer` along with a [Sanbdox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sanne-c0quw?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const list = [1, 2, 3];
const default_states = list.map((item) => Object({ id: item, action: false }));
export default function App() {
  const [li_states, dispatch] = React.useReducer((state, id) => {
    return state.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) return { id: item.id, active: !item.active };
      else return item;
    });
  }, default_states);

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((item) => {
        const cur = li_states.find((s) => s.id === item);
        return (
          <div key={item}>
            <li
              onClick={() => {
                dispatch(item);
              }}
            >
              {item}
            </li>
            <div className={cur.active ? "action" : "info"}> Info {item}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

What's happening here is each time you click any of your LIs, the `dispatch` calls the reducer function inside `React.useReducer` with the ID of the LI and toggles the state of the clicked LI.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this method too

```
const list = ['Start', 'Installation', 'Text Banners', 'Image Banners'];
const links = ['/start', '/installation', '/textbanners', '/imagebanners'];
  
  const [active, setActive] = useState(null)
  const toggleActive = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    setActive(e.target.innerText)
  }
  return (
    <div className={style.dashboard_container}>
      <div className={style.dashboard}>
        <ul>
          {list.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li className={active == item ? style.active : ''} key={index} onClick={toggleActive}>{item}</li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).